# Filtered lookup column with 'WHERE' clause

Tags: lookup-column

I have 2 lists: List 1 and List 2.

List 1 has 2 columns 'supplier' and 'broker'.

List 2 has 2 columns 'nature' and 'supplier name'.

My requirement is 'supplier' is a lookup from 'supplier name' column of 'List 2' where 'nature="supplier"' and 'broker' is a lookup from 'supplier name' of 'List 2 where 'nature="broker"'.

I am working on SharePoint foundation 2010 .

Things I have tried :

1. Using sharepoint designer 2010 : I created new form fields but getting error that says "Unable to display this web part" .
2. C# code for event handling mainly on item added event : the query doesnt return any result . Below is my code .

   ```
   private void SetCalculatedTitle(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       SPList _supplierMaster ;
       if (properties.ListTitle == "PurchaseMaster")
       {
           if (properties.EventType == SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded ||
           properties.EventType == SPEventReceiverType.ItemUpdated)
           {

             SPListItem _listItem = properties.ListItem;



               using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://****/"))
               {

                   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                   {
                        _supplierMaster = web.Lists["PARTY"];

                   }

               }

              // SPWeb web = new SPWeb("http://****/");// SPContext.Current.Web;



               SPQuery queryEmployee = new SPQuery();
               queryEmployee.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='nature' LookupId='True' /><Value Type='Lookup'>supplier</Value></Eq></Where>";
               SPListItemCollection result = _supplierMaster.GetItems(queryEmployee);


               _listItem["SupplierName"] = result;



                                   this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
                                   _listItem.SystemUpdate();
                                   this.EventFiringEnabled = true;


        }
   ```

Using this code i was just trying to find that result should retrieve the desired value while debugging but couldn't get it.

I have no experience in C# neither in SharePoint .

Please give me a detailed solution if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seem to me like you need something like this Codeplex [field](https://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/). It's custom field like standard lookup but it allows you to specify query when adding column to the list. I use it and it works fine for list. There's problem in document libraries with Office information panel (relevant only for Office documents).

Comment: This is a very nice addon.  I have a question too about a caml query in case it helps someone: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163537/caml-query-for-filtered-lookup-column